# Cassandra - Import from CSV and create new table?

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I am attempting to copy a csv file in a Cassandra table using

so in cqlsh, something like:

```
COPY mytable FROM 'test.csv' WITH header=TRUE;
```

problem is that in practice, my CSV file has more than a hundred columns. Is it necessary to define each column using

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (<all my columns here>);
```

or hopefully, is there some way to create the table f
rom the column headers? I mean, I could write a short python script that reads the column headers and then outputs them into a format i can just copy and paste into , but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to create a table from CSV in CQLSH. Unfortunately CSV doesn't contain information about columns' types, so CQLSH can't figure that out to create a table.

Comment: Ah, good to know, thanks. Could you suggest any practical way of going about getting around this? Assuming, for instance, I can consider every column type text

Comment: A perl/python script could easily create a CQL DDL definition for you. At least a stub, which you can adjust manually.